# Trying to get a script to highlight weekends when Month is chose on a Google Sheet numbered 1-31

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Sheet mileage template that is numbered 1-31.  Every month, I change the date, clear the numbers from the previous month, then highlight all the weekends.

I am just a beginner with scripts.  I did two scripts to clear the numbers and formatting which is working, but I would like to be able to put the month and year at the top and have a script to color format all the weekends for that month.  I don't even know where to start.

Example of our travel log:

[image: Example of our travel log]

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See [How much research effort is expected of stackoverflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for official documentation, free resources and more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to create a spreadsheets with sheets that represents the months of the current year.  It will will be easy to locate week ends because they are the last two columns on the right.

The first function is just a helper function.  The other one is the one you should call.

```
function monthlyCalendar11(m, wsd, ret, sh, ss) {
  sh.clear();
  const td = new Date();
  const [cy, cm, cd] = [td.getFullYear(), td.getMonth(), td.getDate()];
  const dA = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
  const oA = [...Array.from(Array(7).keys(), idx => dA[(idx + wsd) % 7])]
  let dObj = {};
  let midx = {};
  let rObj = { cA: null, roff: null, coff: null };
  oA.forEach(function (e, i) { dObj[e] = i; });
  const mA = [...Array.from(new Array(12).keys(), x => Utilities.formatDate(new Date(2021, x, 15), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MMM"))];
  mA.forEach((e, i) => { midx[i] = i; })
  let cA = [];
  let bA = [];
  let wA = [null, null, null, null, null, null, null];

  const year = new Date().getFullYear();
  let i = midx[m % 12];
  let month = new Date(year, i, 1).getMonth();
  let dates = new Date(year, i + 1, 0).getDate();
  cA.push([mA[month], dates, '', '', '', '', '']);
  bA.push(['#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff']);
  cA.push(oA)
  //bA.push(['#ffff00', '#ffff00', '#ffff00', '#ffff00', '#ffff00', '#ffff00', '#ffff00']);
  let d = [];
  let ddd = [];
  for (let j = 0; j < dates; j++) {
    let day = new Date(year, i, j + 1).getDay();
    let date = new Date(year, i, j + 1).getDate();
    if (day < wA.length) {
      wA[dObj[dA[day]]] = date;
    }
    if (cy == year && cm == month && cd == date) {
      rObj.roff = cA.length;
      rObj.coff = dObj[dA[day]];
    }
    if (dA[day] == oA[wA.length - 1] || date == dates) {
      cA.push(wA);
      //bA.push(['#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff']);
      wA = ['', '', '', '', '', '', ''];
    }
  }
  if (!ret) {
    rObj.cA = cA;
    sh.getRange(1, 1, rObj.cA.length, rObj.cA[0].length).setValues(cA);
    if (rObj.roff && rObj.coff) {
      sh.getRange(1, 1).offset(rObj.roff, rObj.coff).setFontWeight('bold').setFontColor('red');
    }
  } else {
    rObj.cA = cA;
    return rObj;
  }
}
```

Run the below function to create a calendar spreadsheet. Please note it will delete all other sheets.  It assume January is alway the left most sheet and that there position indexes maintain the same indexes of the months in the Javascript Date() object

```
function createCalendar() {
  const css = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const months = [...Array.from(new Array(12).keys(), x => Utilities.formatDate(new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), x, 1), css.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "MMMM"))];
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(gobj.globals.testfolderid);
  const files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  var id;
  var ss;
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    let file = files.next();
    if (file.getName() == 'Calendar') {
      id = file.getId();
    }
  }
  if (id) {
    ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  } else {
    ss = SpreadsheetApp.create('Calendar');
    let file = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId());
    file.moveTo(folder);
    months.forEach(e => ss.insertSheet(e));
  }
  ss.getSheets().filter(sh => !~months.indexOf(sh.getName())).forEach(sh => ss.deleteSheet(sh));
  ss.getSheets().forEach((sh, i) => {
    monthlyCalendar11(i, 1, false, sh, ss);
  });
```

Each sheet looks similar to this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I should have put an example of the sheet we have to use:

Comment: Not a big deal I had most of this already done for my own use.

Comment: Yeah an image would have been a good idea

Comment: I added an image in my question area that reads example of our travel log[1]